# Уход модераторов сети Stack Exchange

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, кризис-2019

По всему Stack Exchange модераторы [покидают](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) свои посты. Кто-нибудь может рассказать, что вообще происходит? Коснётся это каким-либо образом StackOverflow на русском?

Comment: Поделитесь пруфами.

Comment: Там же прямо по ссылке все расписано, есть даже список ушедших модераторов.

Comment: Интересно, сколько времени провисел бы подобный пост у нас? :-P

Comment: @VladD пост о бане Qwertiy до сих пор висит, так что ответ - точно больше года.

Comment: @PashaPash: Приходите в неназываемое место, у нас там для вас найдётся большааая коллекция удалённых, гораздо более невинных постов.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за приглашение, но у меня в последний год :( слишком мало свободного времени, и нет возможности общаться в формате чата, так что между неназываемым и SO вынужден выбирать SO.

Comment: @PashaPash: Удачи вам на SO.

Comment: @PashaPash и кстати, в том чате можно общаться на многие темы отличные от SO, и это достаточно интересно

Comment: @VladD А чего вы в телеграм не хотите?

Comment: @Cerbo: В телеге нету прайвеси

Comment: Вообще, я вижу символичным и очень закономерным различие между реакцией на эту ситуацию англоязычного сообщества и модераторов, и русскоязычного. Это лучше всяких слов показывает разницу в менталитете и иллюстрирует, почему принятое _кое-где_ слепое копирование правил большого SO не может работать.

Comment: @VladD вы считаете что в англоязычном сообществе модераторов все, как один, возмутились, в то время как в русском тупо согласились с решением администрации? К сожалению, это не так, и в англоязычном сообществе есть и те, кто читает что с Моникой обошлись слишком мягко. Просто англоязычных модераторов много (намного больше, чем русскоязычных), и среди них нашлись те, кто решили уйти (=кто мог позволить себе уйти, не бросив сообщество без модерации).

Comment: @PashaPash Думаю Влад имел в виду что они вообще это сделали.

Comment: @Cerbo они - это это слишком большой обобщение. Хотя, в чем то он прав. Пойду напишу развернутый ответ :(

Comment: Тем временем в штаб-квартире SO: Let me play Erica on the world's smallest volksempfänger.

Answer (score 15):

Там просто очень много чего случилось. Большую часть инфы можно найти в посте по вашей ссылке, но если кратко:

1. Смена лицензии. Очень многие восприняли это в штыки, т.к. обычно смена лицензии подразумевает опрос участников на то, хотят они этого или нет. Или же, по крайней мере, оставить старые сообщения по старой лицензии. Компания отмалчивается по поводу легальности данного действия. Тим пытается что-то сказать по поводу того, что у них руки связаны в этом плане. Очень странно это выглядит для многих.
2. Давняя история с тем, что сотрудники компании конфликты в соц. сетях иногда разрешают не самым лучшим образом. Про это Моника ещё год назад писала.
3. Сообщение Моники:

   > They did this not because I've done anything to violate SE policies
   >   (which I have not done), but because they think I will in the future
   >   violate a thoughtcrime-style provision of a Code of Conduct change
   >   that hasn't been made yet.

   Она очень часто задавала, скажем так, неудобные вопросы. Подозреваю, что какое-то из сообщений стало последней каплей. Как на самом деле, сложно сказать.
4. Новый CEO компании.
5. Шумиха вокруг кривой рекламы на сайтах SE.
6. Ну и вишенка на торте - изменение CoC. Из того, что пишут люди:

   - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334051/260198
   - [Are there specific issues with unwelcoming behavior toward LGBTQ persons on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334058/260198)

Более подробная информация появится в ближайшее время. Но, в любом случае, нас это тоже коснётся. Пока что остаётся только ждать.

Comment: Хочу заметить, что я лично ничего не имею против ЛГБТ, но оно официально запрещено в России. Интересно, наложит это какие-нибудь ограничения на руCoC?

Comment: @AntonSorokin если там что-то и будет, то вроде как будет касаться местоимений/обращений. С законами никакого конфликта не будет.

Comment: @ Suvitruf Печально :(

Comment: @AntonSorokin, вроде бы ведь только пропаганда среди молодёжи запрещена, а не сами люди?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не знаю, не разбирался в этом вопросе

Comment: Да, инфы по ссылке полно, банально нет времени всё это читать, тем более там не технический английский. Насчёт смены лицензии, на постсоветском пространстве, на мой взлгяд, отношение к лицензиям индифферентное, что есть лицензия, что её нет -- без разницы.

Comment: @nempoBu4, ну, не всегда и не везде) Есть сообщество `SCP Foundation`, и у них был нехилый срач с меж нашими и англоговорящими когда наши лицензию поменяли. Так что часть народа в курсе что есть нюансы)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ого, следите. Там ещё срачик недавно был, когда особо умный решил навариться на этом деле.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, про лицензии наши начинают задумываться, когда появляется необходимость иметь дело с иностранцами )

Comment: @Suvitruf, таки приходится следить( В контакте с их админами, но пока не в курсе есть ли развитие в ситуации с последним персонажем с которым, к сожалению, знаком лично

Comment: Насчёт ЛГБТ, в русском языке есть только мужской, женский и средний роды. Какие-либо местоимения и обращения для тех, кому не нравится его биологический пол, в русском языке не предусмотрены ) Да и человек должен тогда везде и всюду кричать о своих половых предпочтениях. Что как-то странно для сайта с техническими вопросами про программирование )

Comment: Имхо, вот [тут](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6718/brothers-i-must-go) человек написал довольно информативно о новом CoC. Это вот особенно внушает: _«If person A comes along and demands that I refer to them by their "preferred pronoun" (even if it is a mismatch for their genetic sex or the grammar of the language being spoken) and I refuse, that's considered an insult. Now if I avoid pronouns altogether by sticking to proper names or disengaging from the individual, that's being considered an insult too.»_

Comment: @Yaant нам с нашими модераторами ещё предстоит этот вопрос обдумать. Но да, звучит весьма, хм, пугающе.

Comment: Звучит дико. Даже если всё правда, я слабо представляю, как можно следить за "disengaging from the individual ... considered an insult too".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat С такого individual'а станется и самому пожаловаться, что его ущемляют игнором. Специально можно и не следить.

Comment: @Yaant Защититься от этого несложно: можно ответить в духе "Ладно, буду использовать нужное местоимение. Но помочь ничем не могу, извини". А потом заигнорить. Не будут же за такое банить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat В свете происходящих событий, не стоит быть так уж уверенным, что не будут.

Comment: @Yaant Так и представляю. "@username Называй меня на %местоимение%. А еще напиши за меня эту программу, и быстро!" Не ответишь или откажешься помогать - нарушил СоС... :Р

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если я правильно понимаю, то игнорирование приравнивается к нарушению. Это и модераторов касается. Но, посмотрим, когда они это опубликуют. Сейчас чего толку гадать.

Comment: Ну и что бы не быть голословным: в новом God Of War белого героя озвучивал афроамериканец и все молчали, а потом выходит Devil May Cry 5, где второстепенного темнокожего героя озвучивает белый актер, так все забурлили... Вышел новым Mortal Combat, где Соню озвучивает девушка из каких-то реальный единоборств, так игру раскритиковали, так как эта девушка когда-то отказалась выходить на ринг против трансгендера...

Comment: А про шумиху вокруг устоявшегося технического термина master/slave, где начали продвигать, что это отсылка к рабовладенчеству, я вообще молчу... Вроде, потом некоторые разработчики переделали все это в каких-то издателей и фоловеров .

Comment: @iluxa1810 чтобы немного прояснить ситуацию - Моника (как и в целом англоязычное сообщество модераторов) вообще нейтрально относилась к гендер-нейтральным местоимениям, и общий шум в англоязычном сегменте вызван не тем, что "модератора сняли за местоимения", а тем, что никто не понимает, за что именно сняли.

Comment: @nempoBu4 в английском языке тоже только три рода. Род, биологический пол и гендер - это не одно и то же. Гендер - это социальное понятие, и оно достаточно сильно меняется со временем. Достаточно яркий пример - это привязка цвета к гендеру (розовый-девочки, синий-мальчики). Лет 100 назад было ровно наоборот. Просто ситуация, когда в обществе разделение на два строгих гендера размывается, отражается в языке. Потому что размытие есть, и его надо как-то называть. Иначе было бы "нет, тебе нельзя серьгу в ухо, ведь в русском языке нет слова для определения того, кем ты станешь!" :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat насчет игнорирования - с Моники сняли ромб разу после вопроса "можно ли в таком случае использовать ник, или просто уйти от общения с пользователем". Именно поэтому сейчас шум.

Comment: @PashaPash Это всё понятно. Русский язык достаточно гибкий. Но я рассматриваю данный вопрос в контексте технической тематики. И меня интересует, появится ли в итоге необходимость отвечать с использованием феминативов человеку, который считает себя женщиной, например: "_В вашей классине `SomeClassine` для свойствы `SomePropertrix` используется методница `BadWomethod`. Необходимо заменить её на методницу `GoodWomethod`._"? :)

Comment: @nempoBu4 А кто-то идентифицировал себя как боевой вертолет или тостер.

Comment: @nempoBu4 Об этом уже в одном из вопросов писали, что да, на самом SO таких проблем нет, ибо сложно кого-то оскорбить кодом, да и пол тут не важен 99.999% случаем. А вот на воркплейсе проблема уже реальная, поскольку там уже пол/цвет кожи/страна начинают влиять на ответ.

Comment: Omg teh dorama. Традиционно в таких случаях открывать три независимых форка, на которых будет жив дух старой школы того SO.

Comment: Shog9 и Robert Cartaino уволены.
Великолепно, зачистка компании StackExchange от здравого смысла завершена.

Answer (score 10):

У нас столько же информации, сколько и у вас: мы читаем те же самые темы на метамете. Это похоже связано с предстоящими изменениями Code of Conduct — и нам тоже очень хочется знать официальную информацию от администрации. В чате уже спрашивали КМ и он пообещал [написать и узнать подробности](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51891958#51891958). Пока ждём информации.

Насколько это коснётся SO на русском — вероятно, если действительно речь идёт о изменении правил сети, то они автоматически будут применяться к каждому сайту сети, в том числе разумеется и к нашему.

Про себя лично могу сказать, что для меня как модератора одного из сайтов сети so эта история пока является слишком далёкой. С отставленным модератором я не знаком, поэтому на личном знакомстве солидарно положить ромб неуместно. Я на метамете видел разные позиции, в том числе, что ушедшие модераторы просто устали, поэтому отставка Моники была скорее поводом. Не знаю, насколько это верно, мне кажется, что такая причина если и была, то не основной.

По поводу предстоящих изменений Code of Conduct если они будут у меня пока никакой информации нет, поэтому как-то заранее возмущаться против того, чего ещё нет как-то глупо. Я планирую мониторить тему потенциальных изменений CoC и принять участие в их обсуждении на английских сайтах (когда это будет спущено на все сайты сети будет поздно), что рекомендую и всем неравнодушным участникам.

Comment: Я не думаю, что кто-нибудь из модераторов русского SO оставит свой пост в связи со всеми этими событиями. На мой взгляд, это было бы как минимум странно )

Comment: @nempoBu4 кто знает (¬‿¬ )

Comment: из ушедших или прекративших активность модераторов все делают это как минимум в знак несогласия с тем КАК "изгнали" Монику.

Comment: почти не видел ни у одного из модераторов даже намеков на несогласия с потенциальными изменениями в новый CoC.

Comment: @AntonMenshov потому что CoC новый вживую никто ещё не видел. Я вот пока тоже жду и особо не высказываюсь )

Comment: @Suvitruf может быть и поэтому. Но у меня причины абсолютно другие точно, и о тех, кто уже высказался - у меня сложилось именно такое впечатление.

Comment: @AntonMenshov у меня двоякое отношение. Мне очень не нравится, как SE гасят и разруливают конфликты. Но, в тоже время, если я сниму ромб, то пострадают обычные пользователи.

Comment: @Suvitruf на 100% разделяю это отношение. И сам пока не знаю что делать в итоге. «Перечитывал пейджер. Много думал».

Comment: @Suvitruf Вот поэтому сообщество должно решить снимать или нет, это самый разумный вариант.

Answer (score 9):

Sara Chipps, Director of Public Q&A написала официальный ответ:
[**An Update to our Community and an Apology**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology?cb=1#334248) (самый заминусованный вопрос на супер-мете, мда).

**1.** Дескать, Монику сместили за: "многократные нарушения CoC (правил поведения), и игнорирование замечаний комьюнити-менеджера на эту тему".
<sub>(в оригинале: "repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct and being unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change the behavior")</sub>

Сама Моника в комментариях все отрицает, и просит пруфы.

**2.** Также, обещают разработать точную процедуру смещения модераторов с должности, и в будущем придерживаться ее, если с кем-то из модераторов возникнут проблемы.
<sub>(в оригинале: "we will release an official process around removing moderators. ... If we have to remove a diamond in the future we will follow a published process")</sub>

Как заметили в комментариях, такая процедура [уже существует](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/353058). Видимо про нее забыли?

Comment: А ещё [такой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) есть ответ от David Fullerton, Stack Overflow’s CTO.

Comment: У нас, помнится, тоже была ситуация, когда забаненный участник просил пруфы. Ему, если мне не изменяет память, отказали, издевательски прикрываясь казусной причиной «не разглашаем подробности нарушения для блага нарушителя».

Answer (score 7):

**Уже коснулось**: [отставка модератора PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9559/337980).

**Точно еще коснется**: изменения и\или разъяснения в Code of Conduct не различают на английском сайт, или на любом другом языке. Будет невероятно интересно посмотреть на то как и кто будет переводить новую редакцию (что бы это ни значило) на русский язык. Про аспекты его правоприменения и обсуждения языковых и культурных особенностей я даже и не говорю.

**Может еще коснуться**: отставки модераторов, добровольное удаление аккаунтов пользователей, приостановление активности.

Comment: Приостановление деятельности, это вряд ли. Всегда найдутся те, кто жаждет просветить хоть кого-нибудь

Comment: Сложилось довольно сложная неоднозначная ситуация. На мой взгляд, последнее, что стоит сейчас делать — распространять слухи и догадки, спекулировать. Это лишь всех раззадорит. Пожалуйста, не отчаивайтесь! Если была допущена ошибка, ее исправят.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky абсолютно согласен со всеми предложениями в вашем комментарии, кроме последнего. На последнее - я лишь нерационально надеюсь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "На мой взгляд, последнее, что стоит сейчас делать — распространять слухи и догадки, спекулировать" - администрация SE сама создала такую атмосферу своими молчаливыми действиями и игнорированием вопросов сообщества на мете. Так что ничего кроме догадок  и выводов на основе крох информации не осталось.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Исправят говорите? Shog9 и Robert Cartaino уволены. Великолепно, зачистка компании StackExchange от здравого смысла завершена.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 4 октября я с вами согласился по всем пунктам кроме последнего. К 14 января ситуация выкристаллизовалась в абсолютно простую и однозначную.