# Добровольная отставка модератора PashaPash

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Я решил добровольно уйти с поста модератора сообщества.

[Недавние события со снятием Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/248633) — одна из причин, но не единственная.

К сожалению, я чувствую, что ключевое для меня правило "предполагайте добрые намерения" больше не действует. Ни формально (оно почему-то исчезло из текста при слиянии be-nice в Code of Conduct), ни на практике. От снятия Моники и кризиса 18-го года до некоторых причин закрытия для меня это все последствия нарушения одного и того же правила, всеми подряд, возможно, включая меня.

Я выдвинул свою кандидатуру несколько лет назад только потому, что считал этот подход основным для развития сообщества. Без реального возврата к assume good intentions у меня нет мотивации быть модератором или в каком-то еще виде представлять сообщество.

Я в последнее время и так не был особо активен как модератор (изредка банил накрутчиков <strike>и несогласных</strike>), так что оставшиеся модераторы вполне справятся с разгребанием тревог.

С сайта уходить не собираюсь (не дождётесь!). Удачи текущему модсоставу в борьбе с синим счетчиком!

Comment: Подожду, пока не исчезнет ромб, дабы откатить https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1268/53 ;)

Comment: @edem PP не единственный мод, к слову. Ну и да, откатывать могут любые высокорепы.

Comment: @edem думаю, отсутствие ромба не помешает мне продолжить борьбу с "обзорщиком" и "беседкой" ). Тревога на войну откатов прилетит на ваш откат, не на мой ;)

Comment: @PashaPash цыплят по осени считают, вызов принят)

Comment: Досадно, что волна отставок докатилась и до ruSO...

Comment: Думаю стоит вписаться в [этот список](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat он уже там. только чуть ниже.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Оу, не туда смотрел.

Comment: Nit: хотел написать, что это  ["assume good faith"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith), но оказалось, что be-nice использовало именно "good intentions" (по крайне мере [в той версии, которую я нашёл](https://web.archive.org/web/20141017030429/http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)). Спасибо за труд.

Comment: Если формально посмотреть на голосование, то получается что плюсами голосуем за отставку модератора. Но я не думаю, что активные пользователи меты на самом деле за отставку @PashaPash скорее люди поддерживают взгляды модератора. на обстановку складывающуюся на SO – Но здесь обсуждается не SO, а добровольная отставка модератора. Я против ухода модератора и прошу его остаться, поэтому поставил минус

Comment: @Alexandr_TT это особенность движка - на мете нельзя создать тему без тега обсуждение, дефект, предложение или поддержка. На самом деле это просто объявление, решение было принято до публикации :)

Comment: @PashaPash очень жаль

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Почему досадно?

Comment: Поясню, поставил плюс в поддержку позиции. Отставке конечно не рад

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `Досадно, что волна отставок докатилась и до ruSO.` — потому что там полный п-ц. Экспозиция: в следующей версии Code of Conduct 1) предписывается использовать не he/his/she/her, а те гендерные местоимения, которые указаны в профиле адресата (ve/ver/xe/xem/fae/faer/...); 2) запрещается избегать местоимения при построении предложений, ибо это *misgendering* ("некорректное наименование пола"). Из-за второго пункта в модчате разгорелась дискуссия.

Comment: Так как дискуссия разгорелась вокруг документа, который никто в глаза не видел, Моника написала CM-у письмо с вопросами. Ну а так как её точка зрения - "используйте предпочтительные местоимения *когда используете местоимения*", то на неё сначала накинулись в модчате (включая некоего человека с должностью "director"), а потом по-тихому, без уведомления, забрали ромб "за несоответствие ценностям сообщества", о чём она узнала только по факту, обратив внимание на свой ник.

Comment: И ещё вдогонку: статья Моники "Stack Overflow Inc.: what we say versus what we do": https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/03/stack-overflow-ignores-its-own-rules.html

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev Насчет Моники - не совсем так. Если коротко - она спросила "будет ли нарушением, если буду избегать использования кастомных местоимений, или обращаться по нику". Другой модератор ответил что да, будет, и это будет мисгендеринг. После этого сняли ромб. За это, или нет - непонятно, но у многих сложилось впечатление, что за.

Comment: Меня наконец-то отставили, теперь могу ставить тревоги и ныть про бездействие модераторов :)

Comment: @PashaPash, в сноске [поста](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193) было написано следующее: `I pointed out that as a professional writer I, by training, write in a gender-neutral way specifically to avoid gender landmines, and sought clarification that this would continue to be ok. To my surprise, other moderators in the room said that not using (third-person singular) pronouns at all is misgendering. `.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev ну да, так поэтому и кипит - она может писать тексты без местоимений вообще, причем так, что никто не заметит подвоха. Тем не менее, вопрос "а можно ли так делать" вызвал странную реакцию.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev вообще недавно в чате Антон приводил отличный пример, когда умышленное и неиспользование местоимения может быть нарушением - https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52027322#52027322.

Comment: Но и это ещё не всё. Существует [регламент по отстранению модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/357761), и он, похоже, был грубейшим образом нарушен. Хотя, такое впечатление, что администрация [и не в курсе о его существовании](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/357761) (`Moving forward, we will release an official process around removing moderators` - обратите внимание на "will").

Comment: Хотя, какой там в курсе? Совместные решения модераторов - это так, междусобойчик, для компании их не существует. Так что ничтожность Меты - это [далеко не наша локальная проблема](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387651/2553424). Демократия в принципе не входит в систему ценностей Stack Overflow, Inc.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev входит, но не в том виде, в котором некоторые ожидают :)

Comment: вот это жееесть, куда катится этот грёбаный мир со своей ПК (я про местоимения)

Comment: Что такое "синий счетчик"?

Comment: @smellyshovel индикатор тревог в мод очереди

Comment: @PashaPash, сожалею о том, что вы ушли! Мне и другим будет вас не хватать! Благо дарю вам за ваш труд! Только сейчас обнаружил это печальное известие.

Comment: С сайта уходить не собираетесь, однако всё же ушли... Почему?

Answer (score 30):

@PashaPash пожалуйста, не уходите, без вас будет реально хуже.
Если образно, то с вашим уходом рухнет одна из стен безопасности нашего общего дома.

Если я не ошибаюсь, есть вещи в модерации сайта, которые    умеете виртуозно  делать только вы.
Конечно труд модератора очень тяжёл, - отрицательных эмоций намного больше, чем положительных. Вообще хвалить сейчас не принято, только жёстко критиковать, но знайте, что ваш труд был всегда ценен, и виден простым пользователям.
Пожалуйста, не спешите с решением.

Comment: однажды и я так ушёл:D

Comment: Полностью согласен!

Answer (score 18):

Когда что-то идёт не так, надо не уходить, а пытаться исправить. Ведь если несогласные будут уходить, то на их место придут согласные и от этого лучше не станет. Лучше бы ты передумал и остался. Но в любом случае желаю успехов в достижении задуманных целей.

Comment: "Ведь если несогласный будут уходить, на их место придут согласные и от этого лучше не станет." — это не зависимость.

Comment: "а пытаться исправить", как например?

Comment: @Cerbo, ну, как-нибудь, как получится.

Comment: @Cerbo, я предлагаю софтверное решение: 
1) Каждый пользователь заполняет анкету, как его/ее называть they/she/he/*any*, а для неанглийских сайтов и на их языке. На португальском, как оказалось, есть только он(и) (мн. ч м.р.) и она(и)  (мн. ч ж.р.). В старинном русском этому соответствовало оне. 
2) При написании ответов/вопросов/ комментариев сайт на каждое местоименее переспрашивает: «пользователь <имя п> просил/а/и называть их/ее/его так-то, вы точно хотите использовать это местоимение?», с вариантами ответа «упс, поправьте меня» или «я про программу/код/другое». И все будут счастливы.

Comment: @user244413, _"вы написали "прилагаю", а файл не добавили"_ ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, не «прилагаю», а «предлагаю». В смысме предлагаю создать :).
Но после некоторых размышлений я нашла  недостатки у этого решения. Что будет, если пользователь вдруг меняет свое местоимение? Все уже написали ответы и комментарии с предыдущим местоимением, а пользователь, например, вдруг просит называть его  they  дабы известить мир о своей беременности. Все предыдущие упоминание сразу начинают нарушать Code of Conduct.

Comment: @Qwertiy продолжение — Поэтому у предлагаю уточненный вариант: Пункт 1) прошлого варианта остается как было. 2) При написании ответов/вопросов/ комментариев сайт на каждое местоименее переспрашивает: «Вы про пользователя сайта? Если да, то введите имя». И связывает их специальной ссылкой.  При смене местоимения пользователя оно автоматически меняется везде. Для русского языка также надо будет хранить падеж местоимения. При желании можно привязать и глаголы, А можно плюнуть и не привязывать. Тут все равно безграмотно пишут. Как вы думаете, можно предложить такое на главной Мете?

Comment: @user244413 падежи есть не только в русском языке. В других языках они могут быть другие или в другом количестве (например, 4 в немецком).

Comment: @user244413 Старые ничего нарушать не будут, так раньше у человека было другое обращение. Человека произвели в рыцари и теперь он законно требует называть его "сир", но ведь раньше он не был рыцарем поэтому старое обращение "смерд" в старых сообщениях ничего не нарушает.

Comment: А если у этого рыцаря очень нежная душа и его ранит даже напоминание  о том, что он был смердом? А если это безобразие увидит другой рыцарь и закричит «Наших тут обижают!!1»  Чувства здесь важнее логики.

Answer (score 9):

Большое спасибо, что в течение почти четырёх лет помогали Stack Overflow на русском оставаться лучшим местом для поиска ответов на вопросы по программированию на русском языке. За время пребывания на посту модератора вы успели обработать 10 515 тревог и 6 768 вопросов и ответов, отмеченных сигналом тревоги.

Выражаю огромную благодарность за работу с сообществом в чате и на Мете, [отстаивание ключевых ценностей](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values) нашего сообщества, терпение и заботу об участниках сайта, в том числе коллегах модераторах. Команде модераторов будет очень не хватать вас и вашего взвешенного взгляда.

Ещё раз большое спасибо от лица всего сообщества Stack Overflow на русском!

Comment: "от лица **всего** сообщества Stack Overflow на русском" даже от тех, кто отбывал "срок" по ограничению пользования ruSO в следствии принятых решений PashaPash?)

Comment: @edem, а почему бы нет? Тем более, никто из забаненных не в курсе, кто именно их забанил. Ну ладно, почти никто. А PashaPash был, пожалуй, самым общительным модератором до последних выборов, а может и после тоже. И под общительностью я подразумеваю не баны, а именно общение в чате и на мете.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему нет? Ну хотя бы по терверу один недовольный найдётся уж точно. Слишком грубое обобщение, хотя и распространённое.

Comment: @Qwertiy: В курсе, в курсе

Comment: @VladD, [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100057/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).