# Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2020

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В преддверии [выборов в модераторы сообщества за 2020 год](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4), мы планируем провести сессию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами в модераторы. Сессия даёт возможность участникам сообщества задать интересующие их вопросы кандидатам. Участие полностью добровольное.

- Ближайшую неделю любой участник может предложить свой вопрос к  кандидатам в модераторы ответом к этому вопросу. Пожалуйста, добавляйте *один вопрос к кандидатам в одном ответе*.
- Команда развития сообществ предоставит небольшой набор базовых вопросов. Первые *два* из них обязательно войдут в список вопросов кандидатам. Остальные попадут в него только в том случае, если сообщество не предложит достаточно интересных вопросов.
- Через неделю, команда развития сообществ выберет **до 8 вопросов от участников сообщества, набравших наибольшее количество голосов**. Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к двум вышеупомянутым обязательным вопросам. Команда развития сообществ оставляет за собой право вносить правки в вопросы так, чтобы они соответствовали выборам. В любом случае, если возникнут какие-либо замечания по содержанию вопросов, мы постараемся описать их в виде комментариев, дав автору возможность внести изменения.
- Как только сообщество определится с вопросами, будет создан новый вопрос, предназначенный для сбора ответов от кандидатов.
- Сессия вопросов и ответов — это прекрасная возможность понять, как кандидат смотрит на существующие в настоящий момент проблемы нашего сообщества. Хотите что–то узнать о будущем модераторе нашего сообщества? Добавьте ответ к этой публикации содержащий любой вопрос, который вы хотите задать кандидату.
- Кроме того, любой участник сообщества, может задать любой другой свой вопрос кандидатам или уточнить один из существующих в [основном чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Если у вас есть вопросы о выборах, пожалуйста, оставьте **комментарий к этому вопросу**.

---

**Обновление**

Вопросы больше не принимаются. Итоговый список вопросов: [Выборы модераторов сообщества 2020: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10769/6).

Comment: Мало вам событий в 2020, ещё и тут выборы решили добавить.

Comment: Могу ли я добавить вопрос, если я хочу потом предложить свою кандидатуру на выборы ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Написано: _"Ближайшую неделю **любой участник** может предложить свой вопрос к кандидатам в модераторы ответом к этому вопросу."_

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica да, можете: одно другого не исключает.

Answer (score 12):

Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Answer (score 11):

У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать.
На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/213987)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Answer (score 8):

Чего, по Вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как Вы планируете восполнить это?

Answer (score 7):

В этом ответе вы можете найти набор базовых вопросов, призванных раскрыть как можно более общую информацию о кандидате. Как написано в инструкциях выше, первые два вопроса гарантированно появятся в итоговой сессии вопросов и ответов. Остальные — только в том случае, если сообщество опубликует недостаточно вопросов. Если вы считаете, что какой-то вопрос из списка, помимо двух верхних, должен войти в итоговую сессию, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в виде отдельного ответа в этом вопросе.

- Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?
- Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

- Что, по вашему мнению, должен делать модератор?
- «Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?
- Каким образом статус модератора сделает ваши действия более эффективными в сравнении с ситуацией, когда вы просто наберете 10 или 20 тысяч баллов репутации?
- Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Answer (score 7):

Вопрос не касается модерации, а больше, чтобы понять взгляды. Почему вы сидите на SOru, если есть SOen? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Answer (score 7):

*Обсудим отношения между вами и избирателями.*

Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором?

Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Согласитесь ли вы на голосование на Мете по вашему снятию, если сообщество будет вами недовольно, или будете прятаться за числами («25 недовольных на Мете — это ничтожно малая доля из всего сообщества» и тому подобная аргументация)? Если голосование будет не в вашу пользу, уйдёте ли вы добровольно, или будете придумывать, почему именно данное голосование нерелевантно и ни к чему вас не обязывает?

---

Вопросы составлены по остывшим следам событий двухлетней давности, и не являются ни в коей мере плодом праздного ума.

Answer (score 7):

*Обсудим, кто ваш истинный босс.*

Как будущий модератор, будете ли вы считать себя представителем компании перед другими участниками, или представителем участников перед компанией?

Например, в случае конфликта интересов между компанией и сообществом (пример: случай с Моникой) будете ли вы защищать интересы сообщества (даже если это будет стоить вам модераторской позиции) или же интересы компании?

Важный частный случай: допустим, некий участник подвергся бану и требует публичного оглашения причин и конкретики; будете ли вы прятаться за буквой правил («мы вам не расскажем причины, правила запрещают, а это нужно чтобы защитить вас от не знаю кого») или открыто сможете обосновать своё решение?

---

Вопросы составлены по остывшим следам событий двухлетней давности, и не являются ни в коей мере плодом праздного ума.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно ли вырезать из вопросов/комментариев приветствия и "спасибо"?

Comment: А также, нужно ли добавлять к комментариям приветствия и "спасибо"?

Comment: @Kromster вроде же есть обсуждение на мете, что спасибы и приветствия надо удалять, потому что это лишняя информация. Ну а добавлять вообще странно :)

Answer (score 4):

В каком случае, либо при каких обстоятельствах Вы сложите, либо хотели бы сложить с себя полномочия модератора?

Comment: А бывало недобровольно? :)

Comment: @dIm0n, бывало. Да хоть тот же пример Моники.

Comment: @mymedia а на ruSO такое было?

Comment: @dIm0n, однажды чуть было не докатилось до такого. Квертий не даст соврать.

Comment: @dIm0n Бармалей.

Comment: Пока из добровольных --  PashaPash сложил: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9559/213987

Answer (score 4):

*Обсудим, как вы будете разрешать личные конфликты.*

Считаете ли вы критику в свою сторону или публично выраженное несогласие с вами агрессией?

Будете ли вы пытаться запретить распространение критических отзывов о вас на других платформах (например, путём банов и удаления ссылок)?

Будете ли вы распространять порочащую других (плохих, по вашему мнению) участников информацию, пользуясь модераторскими привилегиями?

---

Вопросы составлены по остывшим следам событий двухлетней давности, и не являются ни в коей мере плодом праздного ума.

Answer (score 0):

Что вы считаете нужно делать с вопросами/ответами содержащими вредоносный код? Что делать с участниками их публикующими?