# Выборы модераторов сообщества 2020: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

Каждый участник, выдвигающийся на позицию модератора сообщества, имеет возможность поделиться своими мыслями с коллегами [по основным наболевшим вопросам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10742/6) нашего сообщества. Ниже представлены пять вопросов от участников к вам, как кандидату, в дополнение к трём вопросам от [команды управления сообществами](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/274323).

### Ссылки на ответы кандидатов:

<sub>(В хронологическом порядке)</sub>

- [ryzen](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10771/186999)
- [Victor VosMottor](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10774/186999)
- [Anton Nikolaev](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10782/186999)
- [eanmos](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10784/186999)
- [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10791/186999)
- [Sheridan](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10792/339283)
- [Barmaley](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10793/5648)
- [Komdosh](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10794/339283)
- [shalor1k](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10795/236727)
- [Pavel Durmanov](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10796/236727)

### Инструкция: как отвечать на вопросы

1. Скопируйте шаблонный текст вопросов.
2. Вставьте его в новый ответ.
3. В начале поставьте своё имя и ссылку на профиль.
4. Пишите свои ответы после каждого блока цитаты и перед `---`, вот так:

   ```
    > Текст вопроса.

    Ваш ответ здесь.

    ---
   ```

### Памятка для кандидатов

- Ваша задача, как кандидата, крайне проста — опубликовать ваши мысли по всем обозначенным ниже вопросам одним ответом *на этот вопрос*.
- Пожалуйста, добавьте ваше имя (псевдоним на сайте) в самом начале ответа, чтобы другие участники понимали, чьи ответы они читают в данный момент.
- Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование как в этой публикации для выделения вопросов и ваших ответов к ним.

Как только все кандидаты разместят свои ответы, мы будем использовать данный вопрос как основу для принятия решений, чтобы каждый участник, который будет голосовать, понимал, почему он решил голосовать именно за данного кандидата.

#### Несколько слов о модераторах сообщества

Модератор сообщества – призвание, а не должность. Вам не обязательно быть «лучшим» специалистом среди коллег в определенной области (хотя разбираться в предмете все–таки стоит), чтобы быть модератором сообщества, но вам обязательно быть хорошим человеком, добрым, отзывчивым. На [Stack Overflow на русском мы в первую очередь ставим во главу угла наших коллег, уважение и доверительные отношения друг к другу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values). И если ранее ваша «общественная репутация» в глазах коллег строилась на базе ваших знаний, вопросов и ответов, то после того, как вы станете модератором, сообщество будет ценить вас за вашу добродетель не меньше, чем за профессиональные навыки.

Без модераторов крайне сложно создать по-настоящему дружное, интересное сообщество, а без сообщества, Stack Overflow – это просто набор битов на жёстком диске. Мы, люди, и есть Stack Overflow! Если вы верите в то, что можете менять мир вокруг себя к лучшему, добро пожаловать в нашу команду модераторов!

Желаю удачи, кандидаты!

> <sub>Тут же хотелось бы обратиться к сообществу, тем, кто будет отдавать свой голос за того или иного кандидата.</sub>
>
> <sub>Коллеги, пожалуйста, подойдите крайне ответственно к выбору модераторов! Модераторы — это фундамент сообщества. Они являются опорой для нас всех в первую очередь в случаях, когда что–то идет не так. Прежде чем отдать свой голос, подумайте, кого бы вы хотели увидеть в момент, когда с вами или с вашим коллегой на сайте произойдет что–то не так, когда вам понадобится помощь? Того кто спокоен, рассудителен, отзывчив, педантичен и добр? Или кого–то другого, например, кто знает больше анекдотов?</sub>
>
> <sub>Представьте, что вам нужно выбрать делового партнёра, которому вы бы смогли доверить ваше благополучие. Делайте ваш выбор исходя из того, что кандидат уже сделал для сообщества, а не обещает сделать, судите по общечеловеческим навыкам, а не знаниям программирования. В работе с людьми навыки программирования пригодятся мало.</sub>
>
> <sub>**От вашего выбора зависит будущее сообщества!**</sub>

### Вопросы

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/213987)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Comment: По-моему, последний вопрос в списке должен быть другим, согласно голосованию участников за вопросы. Разве нет?

Comment: А выборы потому что просто добираете модераторов или всё-таки кто-то собирается уходить?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov у меня такое ощущение, что просто для привлечения внимания. Ведь во время выборов, как известно, пользовательская активность повышается.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov уходить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov уходить. [A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10777/213987)

Comment: Немного статистики: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/1292407

Answer (score 15):

## Упс, мою кандидатуру сняли. Ну что ж, если никто ответ не удаляет -- оставлю для истории (и <sub>+8</sub> <sub>+9</sub> +12) ;)

Сняли за временный бан на MSE.

---

## [Victor VosMottor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337540/victor-vosmottor?tab=profile)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Ну, я бы сделал так:

0. (Опциональный шаг: первые споры можно просто удалить и оставить коммент мол "не надо")
1. Сначала напишу "Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи на StackOverflow", и там попрошу не нарушать правила, если споры заходят слишком далеко (т.е. переходы на личности, оскорбления и т.д.).
2. Если не подействует — ограничу доступ на день-два.

При этом все споры удалять.

Я думаю, этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы участник перестал нарушать правила.

Ну, и, конечно, если это спор основан на фактах и цитатах, и он не нарушает правила — то участник имеет право спорить. Если будет слишком длинно — стоит перенести в чат.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Спрошу модератора: "Зачем?". Если он аргументирует достаточно объективно, не буду спорить. Но, скорее всего, задам вопрос на Мете — пусть сообщество решит.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Смотря какие подробности. Если разглашение этих подробностей может реально нанести вред участнику, тогда нет — не разглашать. Но в большинстве случаев, я думаю, обсуждение обязательно следует инициировать.
Впрочем, модераторы, по-моему, что-то подписывают: по поводу чего следует помалкивать;)

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%84%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Тут я вижу несколько важных моментов:

- Во-первых: какого мнения придерживаюсь я сам?
- Во-вторых: вероятно, надо дать сообщество решить самому.

Я просто не стал бы ничего особенного делать, кроме как инициировать обсуждение. Если кто-то хочет, например, закрывать какие-то вопросы, пусть голосует за это. А кто не хочет, того никто не заставляет. В результате большинство решит. На конкретном примере:

Новогодний конкурс — это веселье своего рода. Это редкое исключение, да и то решили же, что код-гольф и прочие онтопик.
Я бы просто давал его провести, а потом несогласные могут закрывать. По-моему, нужен компромисс.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Текущему модераторскому составу не хватает самих модераторов ;) По-моему, модераторов надо больше, чем сейчас есть. Это ускорит обработку тревог и т.д. Я буду выполнять рутинные работы модераторов и тем самым улучшy сообщество и ускорю модерацию.

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Я люблю это сообщество и искренне верю в возможность создания полноценной базы знаний по программированию на русском! Тем более, если гуглить по-русски, то уже находишь много ответов на свои вопросы на русском языке. Так держать!

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Да, ведь главное — это сообщество, а не ромб. Но, впрочем, я буду выполнять все, что обещаю. Если кто-то будет мной недоволен (если меня выберут), то пусть просто мне это скажет — я выполню его просьбу и/или исправлю свою ошибку. Но я не считаю правильным "складывать полномочия" из-за ошибки. Ошибки надо исправлять, а не сдаваться и уходить из-за них.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Конечно согласен. Бороться буду как полагается — предупреждение, временные баны, полные баны.

Comment: Alt+0151 = тире (—)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ubuntu.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`U`+`2014`+`Enter`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Как то длинно и неудобно. Можно `scrolllock` + три `-`.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor а можно включить типографскую раскладку и AltGr+-

Comment: А временный бан на MSE препятствует участию в выборах? Хотелось бы прозрачности и открытости.

Comment: @VladD https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55343703#55343703

Comment: @dIm0n: А почему это не было показано в самом начале при выдвижении, а только сейчас? Хотелось бы иметь official statement, чтобы потом можно было на него ссылаться. Прозрачность, все дела.

Comment: @VladD не знаю. У участника из чата похоже сразу это окно показало и не дало выдвинуться, а тут уже после выдвижения сняли. Может бан прилетел после выдвижения?

Comment: Я думаю, что ситуация такова: если бан случился на том сайте, где идет выдвижение - сообщение идет автоматически. Однако любой бан - это препятствие к выборам, если нет смягчающих обстоятельств (например, бан был выписан по ошибке или ____вписать соответствующее____). В этом случае, кандидатура снимается вручную.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Всё равно странно. Зачем заставлять человека отвечать на гору сложных, заковыристых вопросов, чтобы потом сказать «ну мы с самого начала знали, что вам нельзя».

Comment: @VladD я думаю, здесь все же "мы с самого начала **могли знать**, что вам нельзя". Это, разумеется, недостаток автоматики системы, тут я с вами полностью согласен.

Comment: @VladD Бан был давно. А на вопросы все равно было интересно ответить. Про бан я спросил Николаса и меня сняли. А так может и не сняли бы.

Comment: за что забанили?

Comment: @Danis Дело было так. Когда была вся эта штука с [Моникой Челлио](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9786/%d0%9a%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f/9787#9787), я поинтересовался на MSE кто является автором аватарки в честь Моники (я ее до сих пор ношу.)...

Comment: ...Вопрос закрыли. Потом переоткрыли. Потом начали закрывать снова. Тут, значит, я решил схитрить и сделать так: удалить вопрос, а через два дня востановить и начать конкурс. Просто мне действительно было интересно, кто же таки автор вопроса. Узнав про этот "приемчик" один из модераторов MSE (не буду говорить кто) вопрос мне удалил, но я так сказать не сдался, взял свой другой удаленный вопрос (мной), отредактировал его, сделав его полным дупликатом вопроса про аватарку и начал конкурс, за что получил бан на неделю от другого модератора MSE.

Answer (score 11):

## [Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley?tab=profile)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Для меня такие участники самые ценные. Ибо в споре рождается истина - все как в реальной жизни, самые ценные люди обычно и самые неуживчивые. Постараюсь найти общие точки соприкосновения с такими участниками и обращу их потенциальный вред от дискуссии на грани фола в пользу от их квалификации и знаний.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Приму как должное. Модератор имеет право на собственное мнение.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Самое лучшее когда модератор незаметен. Я против публичности работы модератора.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - пример), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Если вопрос способствует росту популярности ресурса, как профессионального ресурса, я не буду против. Правила для сообщества, а не сообщество для правил. Правила имеют свойство меняться.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Не хочу и не буду комментировать действия текущего модераторского состава.

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Я не считаю первичной идею о том что SO это база знаний, для меня это скорее среда общения программистов. База знаний это вторично, если будет дружественная и профессиональная среда общения - то будет и база знаний. Пока что русский SO довольно токсичен.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Безусловно. Я уже доказывал это делом и складывал полномочия.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Да, я согласен, но я против того, чтобы ресурс стал как фруктовый кефир:

> Другой держался русла и течение ловил Подальше от крутых берегов. Он
> был как все и плыл как все, и вот он приплыл: Ни дома, ни друзей, ни
> врагов. И жизнь его похожа на фруктовый кефир

Я буду вразумлять *"добрым словом и револьвером"*, в первую очередь, конечно добрым словом. Ресурс должен быть интересным, с интересными дискуссиями, но конечно же в рамках.

Comment: «Я не считаю первичной идею о том что SO это база знаний» — минус мой голос)

Comment: согласен, это и есть точка бифуркации между старым составом и молодежью :)

Comment: Сначала не собирался за вас голосовать. Но вы очень интересно ответили на вопросы. Если мне хватит голосов -- то голос @andreymal 'a компенсирован ;)

Comment: @Majestio, что за своеволие?

Comment: Сорри, я просто первый раз пытался задать вопрос. А как правильно?

Comment: @Majestio задайте его в заявках кандидатов, в чате или тут в комментариях, но не редактируя ответ

Comment: Почему русский SO токсичен? По-моему наоборот, остальные. А тут пока более-менее нормально.

Answer (score 10):

#### [@eanmos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185348/eanmos)

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Если комментарий участника помечается тревогой, значит участник (скорее всего) нарушает правила поведения в сообществе. В любом сообществе нарушение принятых правил и норм встречается санкциями. С другой стороны, мы всегда должны учитывать пользу этого участника для сообщества. И решение в конкретном случае всегда должно быть основано на компромиссе между пользой и вредом, которые приносит участник. Путем беседы с участником нужно постараться минимизировать деструктивные действия, которые он приносит сообществу. Если диалог ни к чему не приводит, принимать дальнейшее решение о судьбе участника сообщество должно коллективно.

Конечно, это сложный вопрос и каждая ситуация должна рассматриваться отдельно. Как и везде здесь есть градация: одно дело, если участник общается несколько резко или грубо, в свойственной ему манере; другое дело — если участник устраивает открытую травлю или открыто оскорбляет других.

Конкретные шаги:

1. Удаление всех деструктивных (оскорбительных, грубых, …) комментариев участника.
2. Диалог с участником, попытка объяснить ему претензии, выдвигаемые сообществом. Возможно, он просто не совсем понимает правила и нормы поведения.
3. Если диалог ни к чему не привел, следует открыто обсудить судьбу участника на мете: готовы ли другие участники терпеть некоторые неудобства взамен на ценные ответы от участника.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Не вижу здесь особой проблемы. В такой ситуации всего два варианта — либо не прав я, либо не прав он. И единственным выходом будет просто обсудить с модератором его решение. Если случится так, что мы вдвоем не сможем прийти к общему знаменателю (что маловероятно), то следует рассмотреть этот вопрос вместе с другими модераторами и принять решение уже вместе.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Модерирование должно быть максимально прозрачно для сообщества. Все, что может быть разглашено публично, должно быть разглашено. Все, что не может — по каким-либо причинам — очевидно, не должно.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности — [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%84%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Единственное возможное решение, которое я вижу, — продолжить обсуждение этого вопроса и, в конце концов, прийти к решению, которое является компромиссным для всех.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Чего им не хватает? Я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос. Сообщество живет и развивается, значит модераторы справляются со свой работой. Может, им всего хватает?

Я вижу некоторые проблемы на SO:

1. Есть много на самом деле *неплохих* вопросов, которые минусуют/критикуют. Да, некоторые из них плохо сформулированы или оформлены, но они все еще полезны для сообщества. И в этом случае мы должны чаще жать кнопочку «править», чем «закрыть».

   Вот, например: [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137211/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2) заминусован, оставлен не самый полезный комментарий. Хотя сам вопрос полезен, понятен и «отражает желание разобраться».
2. Иногда проскальзывают вопросы с просьбой посоветовать литературу, которые закрываются с причиной «Невозможно дать объективный ответ». Неприемлимое решение в таком случае. У нас есть канонические вопросы со списком литературы по определенным темам, поэтому все вопросы такого рода должны закрываться как дубликаты со ссылкой на соответствующий канонический вопрос. Если же такого канонического вопроса не существует, то его необходимо создать.

   Примеры таких вопросов: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248921/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83274/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-c), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069914/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-nunit), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79662/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f), [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/133080/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-php-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8d%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc), [6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297734/bash-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0).
3. Отсутствие консенсуса по поводу вопросов-соревнований.

Не думаю, что эти проблемы имеют место быть именно из-за того, что модераторам «чего-то не хватает». Да и проблемы эти не так критичны, хотя решить их, конечно, надо бы.

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Здесь люди, которых я знаю. Пускай только по никам и аватаркам, но я к ним привык, даже, в какой-то степени, «привязался».

Не думаю, что создать полноценную базу знаний на русском возможно — сфера программирования и системного администрирования слишком быстро развивается, и это развитие идет прежде всего от англоязычного сообщества. Русскоязычное сообщество гораздо меньше, это значит, что англоязычная база знаний всегда будет далеко впереди.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Да, конечно. Если я не смогу выполнить то, что обещаю, то я буду должен сложить полномочия. Это следует из того, что должность модератора предполагает огромную ответственность перед людьми, которые тебя выбрали.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Да, я с ними согласен, потому что эти нормы имеют смысл. Касательно агрессивно настроенных участников см. ответ на первый вопрос.

Comment: *"Если же такого канонического вопроса не существует, то его необходимо создать"* — так кто этим должен заниматься? Модераторы или всё таки участники, задающие такие вопросы?

Comment: @dIm0n, а почему «или»? И модераторы и участники! Правда, участники, *которые задают такие вопросы*, скорее всего не знакомы с тем, что у нас вообще есть такие вещи как канонические вопросы со списком литературы.

Comment: "Здесь люди, которых я знаю. Пускай только по никам и аватаркам, но я к ним привык, даже, в какой-то степени, «привязался»." -- я тоже, хотя я здесь существенно позже ;)

Comment: А причём тут консенсус по поводу соревнований? КМ совершенно чётко заявил, что консенсус сообщества ничего не значит, значит лишь его личное решение.

Comment: @VladD, ну, если все именно так, как вы пишете, то это и называется отсутствие консенсуса. А где именно КМ совершенно четко это заявил? Вы имеете в виду [вот этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10374/185348) ответ на Мете?

Comment: @eanmos: Скорее [вот этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7221/10105). Посмотрите ответ КМа, а также его executive summary, написанное мной в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 10):

### [@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Забаню

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Если лучше разбираюсь в теме вопроса - переоткрою, если нет - оставлю как есть.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Вполне за, если при этом не раскрываются личные данные пользователей.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/213987)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Если единого решения нет - нужно обратиться к основным правилам.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Не хватает людей.

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Смотря какие выбрать критерии полноценности.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Нет!

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Вполне согласен. Вполне придерживаюсь.
Агрессивные участники достойны бана.

---

Comment: Стоит добавить свой ник в шапку ответа

Comment: *"Если лучше разбираюсь в теме вопроса"* — а как узнать, кто лучше разбирается? *"обратиться к основным правилам"* — насколько я понял, если есть обсуждение этого вопроса, то в правилах сайта этот вопрос может быть ещё не прописан

Comment: @dIm0n, модераторов не так много, компетенции каждого уже известны. В большинстве случаев _вопросы_ лишь уточняют более широкие правила.

Comment: _"если ... не раскрываются личные данные"_, — а если участники, которых Вы забаните, попросят публично огласить причину и дадут согласие на разглашение личных данных? Выполните просьбу?

Comment: @nomnoms12, они в этом случае сами могут написать :)

Comment: Ну хотя бы честно (тм)

Comment: Шикарные ответы Если (не дай Бог, конечно) тебе придётся иметь дело со следователем/прокурором и т.д. то с тебя точно не получат никакой лишней информации))

Answer (score 2):

## [Pavel Durmanov](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/236727/pavel-durmanov?tab=profile)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Раз уж этот человек дает полезные ответы, значит он как минимум адекватен (не требует предупреждения/наказания), и, наверное не знаком со всей функциональностью RU SO, расскажу ему о том что у нас есть чаты, где он может вести дискуссии с другими участниками.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Ну думаю что такое произойдет, все модераторы хорошо знакомы с правилами RU SO и делают свои выводы основываясь на этих правилах. Но если таки вдруг такое случится, я скорее всего поговорю с этим модератором, чтобы узнать его мотив. Если модератор таки ошибся (бывает, человеческий фактор), обсудим где он был неправ и переоткроем вопрос с нужными правками.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Думаю что нужно таки обсуждать публично, модераторы должны основывать свои решения на предпочтениях сообщества, а не на своих личных.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - пример), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Тут по моему мнению, у модератора решающий голос, учту мнение сообщества и приму решения основываясь уже на своем мнении об упомянутом вопросе.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Честно говоря не знаю, никогда не был модератором, и особо не следил за их работой. Но если вдруг я стану модератором, у меня будет шанс увидеть как это работает изнутри, и возможно что-то улучшить (или нет).

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

RU SO по моему мнению ресурс для начинающих программистов, такое мнение сложилось из-за сложности вопросов в целом. Если учитывать то, что человек только начинает свой путь, он скорее всего не очень хорошо знает английский язык, и ему будет комфортнее черпать информацию на его родном или знакомом ему языке.
На счет актуальности базы знаний, думаю нет, так как большинство продвинутых тем (книг, etc) таки на английском языке, что хорошо. Без английского языка в айти будет непросто, и нехватка информации на любом другом языке (русском в данном примере) будет вынуждать учить английский.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Возьму ли я доп. обязательства? Не уверен, врать не буду.
Если не смогу выполнять то что пообещал, да, уйду с поста модератора. Я никак не заинтересован удерживать этот пост и понижать качество модерации своим бездействием.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Согласен. Я сторонник переубеждения а не крайних мер, объясню человеку где он был неправ, если ничего не выйдет - буду действовать "по уставу".

Comment: *"расскажу ему о том что у нас есть чаты"* -- а если участник знает про чаты, но всё равно холиварит в комментариях?

Comment: Предупреждение, если не подействует - ограничу доступ.

Answer (score 1):

[@Sheridan](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14955/sheridan)

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Отправка в чат, предупреждения, бан.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Поговорю с модератором. выясню причину. Объясню свою точку зрения, но могу и согласиться с этим самым другим модератором.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Подавляющее большинство решений не стоит обсуждения, они очевидны. Обсуждение оставшихся, при желании сторон, можно и вынести в мету. Не вижу причин не обсудить итересующую участников тему.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение, которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Выслушаю аргументы, посмотрю на общую атмосферу обсуждения и приму решение.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

В целом всё устраивает, просто могу помочь в этой рутине.

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Я не настолько хорошо знаю английский, чтобы вступать дискуссии и даже чтобы подготовить подробный, читабельный ответ.

Полноценная база уже создаётся. Не вижу препятствий для завершения этой работы.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Если сообщество задаст мне вопрос - не вижу причин не отвечать на него. Если сообщество посчитает мои решения настолько плохими, что лучше будет уйти - не вижу причин не уйти. У меня цель - помочь, а не тратить нервы сообщества.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

С нормами согласен. Придерживаюсь. Бороться - стандартным путём: предупреждения -> баны.

Comment: А почему у вас плашка «Новый участник»? По информации из профиля, вы на сайте >6 лет.

Comment: Дык плашка то для местной меты, а участник я ещё с en SO

Answer (score 0):

[**@shalor1k**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/396366/shalor1k)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Вопрос довольно сложный, в силу того, что есть отдельные случаи к которым может понадобиться специальный способ решения ситуации. Но в большинстве случаев в начале нужно сделать человеку предупреждение, по той причине, что человек сам может не подозревать о своём причастии к спорам, если подобное будет повторятся снова и снова, следует ограничить человеку доступ и обязательно указать причину.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Буду стараться выйти с ним на контакт и обсудить данный вопрос, и после посмотреть на ситуацию с его точки зрения.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Если эти подробности несут характер какой-либо личной или конфиденциальной информации, то разглашать их не нужно, обосновывая это тем, что разглашение может нанести вред участнику.Если подробности не несут информации несущей вред участнику, то они могут быть обсуждены на Мете.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - пример), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Я считаю, что наиболее правильный ответ на данный вопрос - поиск компромисса

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Возможно из-за маленького состава модераторы после большого объёма информации могут не совсем объективно закрывать вполне хорошие вопросы. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069914/)

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Здесь, на русском SO, я могу использовать различные фразеологизмы и сравнения (в силу того, что являюсь носителем русского языка) которые способны передать всю суть моей мысли.
По поводу полноценной базы знаний, это зависит от множества различных факторов, но я думаю, что англоязычная база знаний всегда будет на несколько шагов впереди в силу всё большей и большей популярности программирования и системного администрирования.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Да, ведь люди голосующие за меня надеются на полное выполнение моих обещаний.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Да, согласен. Я считаю, что сначала агрессивному участнику следует объяснить ему, что такое поведение на сайте недопустимо, и если участник с этим соглашается, то следует некоторое время следить за соблюдением им, этих норм поведения. Если участник не соглашается и продолжает вести беседу в агрессивном ключе, то его нужно забанить (срок бана зависит от степени агрессивности его диалога).

Comment: А чем вопрос по ссылке хорош? Там же просят субъективный набор источников. Такие вопросы либо закрывают, либо делают дубликатами закреплённых канонических

Comment: @dIm0n Данный вопрос хорош тем , что человек задавший вопрос проявил интерес и решил спросить у более опытных участников

Comment: Среди закрывших вопрос нет ни одного модератора. При чём они тут?

Answer (score -2):

### [@Komdosh](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/184435/komdosh)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

На мой взгляд комментарии не являются ответами и нужны как раз для того, чтобы разъяснить вопрос\ответ, этот спор может уточнить искомую информацию, однако всё зависит от контекста, если автор отстаивает свою правоту грязными методами и оскорблениями, то здесь последуют жёсткие меры пресечения, такого общения.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Будет зависеть от моей компетенции в вопросе, если сталкивался, то посмотрю, что пишут другие по этому поводу и на основании этого уже буду решать переоткрыть или нет.

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Открытость двигает мышление в правильную сторону, за счёт большого количества мнений, но тут надо на контекст смотреть.

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10370/213987)), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Если тревоги такого рода никого не задевают, не вызывают чувств обиды и т.п., то попытаюсь вникнуть в проблему и на основе этого будет решение.

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Времени и сил на модерирование

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Для себя по большей части ищу ответы на английской версии, там достаточно много людей. Нахожусь здесь из-за того, что немного понимаю проблему русскоязычных новичков, которые хотят разобраться в проблеме, но не могут из-за того, что сложно правильно загуглить данную информацию, а из-за языкового барьера очень трудно изъяснить свою проблему на англоязычной версии. На нашем ресурсе довольно много ответов на самые разные вопросы, но на английской версии всегда база будет больше, из-за того что там собраны люди со всего мира.

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

Не считаю, что обязан именно отчитываться. Хотя объяснить проблему, особенно новеньким, считаю нужным. Если пойму, что не выполняю свои обязанности, сложу полномочия.

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «[Нормами поведения](/conduct)»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

Согласен. Вроде придерживаюсь, не помню иного. Обычно агрессии на пустом месте редки, но в таком случае нужно самому быть жёстким и твёрдой рукой выполнять обязанности модератора.

---

Answer (score -6):

[Anton Nikolaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/298159/anton-nikolaev)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество
> ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
> впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Не хотелось бы выделять каких-либо "исключительных" участников сообщества. Не смотря на мою любовь к банам, буду использовать их крайне редко и в основном использовать такую прогрессивную шкалу наказаний: предупреждение -> бан на час -> бан на день -> бан на неделю -> ...

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
> т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
> т. д.?

Напишу этому модератору, обсудим с ним данный вопрос, если не придем к общему мнению, то пойдем на суд других модеров :)

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны
> с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же,
> считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

Сообщений на мете у меня немного (0), хотя я частенько захожу почитать обсуждения здесь. Считаю что нужно обсуждать вопросы публично, ведь модераторы это часть коммунити и вопросы эти касаются всего коммунити.

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую
> необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было
> обсуждение (для предметности - пример), которое однако закончилось
> тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши
> дальнейшие действия как модератора?

Насколько я понял, то речь о том что не все ситуации возможно описать формальными правилами. Буду руководствоваться личным опытом и советами других модеров, за которыми я пойду в модерский чат. (Хотя, если старое обсуждение было скажем год назад, то его стоит возобновить?)

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу?
> Как вы планируете восполнить это?

Не хватает рабочих рук. Я люблю на работе раз в час-два отвлечься на пару минут и почекать
вопросы на СО.

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack
> Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по
> программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

Мне нравится идея развития ру айти коммунити + это сильно поможет начинающим разработчикам, у которых не очень с английским. Что-то в снг же должно развиваться?..

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на
> себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете
> модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым
> сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то,
> что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется
> правилами)?

"С большой силой приходит большая ответственность." (с) :)
Не вижу смысла держаться за ромбик, если у меня не будет возможности выполнять модераторские обязанности. Ну а если кто-то чем-то недоволен, то **бан**... то есть обсудим причину недовольства.

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их
> сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

С нормами согласен. Конечно придерживаюсь. Не хочу повторяться, но "предупреждение -> бан на час -> бан на день -> бан на неделю -> ..."

Answer (score -7):

[ryzen](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/302918/ryzen)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

**Если сообщения помеченные тревогой нарушают правила сообщества - выдам соответствующее предупреждение/наказание.**

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

**Постараюсь найти компромисс, в случае если не получится этого сделать - восстановлю вопрос.**

---

> Что вы думаете по поводу публичности решений модераторов? Вы согласны с тем, что не нужно разглашать подробности публично или, всё же, считаете, что нужно их обсуждать вместе с сообществом на той же Мете?

**Я считаю, что решения модераторов должен видеть каждый, так как это открытое сообщество, если возникнут спорные ситуации - добро пожаловать в обсуждение.**

---

> У вас существует третья однотипная тревога на вопросе, которую необходимо обработать. На мета сайте по подобным вопросам уже было обсуждение (для предметности - пример), которое однако закончилось тем, что сообщество раскололось примерно поровну. Как вы видите ваши дальнейшие действия как модератора?

**Обработаю тревогу, учитывая мнения обоих сторон, решение будет однозначным.**

---

> Чего, по вашему мнению, не хватает текущему модераторскому составу? Как вы планируете восполнить это?

**Я думаю активности и терпеливости, это касается не только модераторов, а и всех участников в целом, хочу заполнить пробел в активности, посещаю ресурс каждый день в свободное время.
Терпеливость освоил при работе с клиентами на работе :)**

---

> Почему вы сидите на Stack Overflow на русском, если есть Stack Overflow на английском? Возможно ли создать полноценную базу знаний по программированию на русском, которая не будет уступать английской?

**Я посещаю как русскую, так и английскую версию Stack Overflow, благо с английским языком всё в порядке. Касательно базы, думаю это возможно, но вся проблема в активности и скорее всего в заинтересованности участников и гостей сообщества. Английскую версию посещают и пополняют чаще, так как английский - международный язык, только из-за этого.**

---

> Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?

**Невозможно угодить каждому, сколько людей - столько и мнений, однако если я не буду устраивать сообщество своими полномочиями - я сложу полномочия. На благо я не конфликтный человек и стараюсь находить выход из любой ситуации.**

---

> Согласны ли вы лично с «Нормами поведения»? Придерживаетесь ли вы их сами? Как вы будете бороться с участниками, ведущими себя агрессивно?

**Согласен полностью, Stack Overflow это база данных, а не место для выяснения отношений или споров не по теме. Буду выдавать наказания и предупреждения по всей мере строгости.**

---

Comment: Думаю, минусы поставили из-за некоторых ответов без конкретики. Например, мне непонятно, как именно и каким порядком действий вы будете находить компромисс. Ведь именно в подробном алгоритме проявляется личность кандидата, которую одни будут хотеть видеть на модераторском посту, а другие нет.

Comment: Да, маловато конкретики. Например, *"Есть ситуации, которые не стоит обсуждать публично, только в рамках привилегированных участников."*. Какие ситуации стоит, а какие нет?

Comment: Конкретезировал ответы на вопросы.

@dIm0n решения модераторов однозначно должны быть публичными, для того, чтобы их в случае чего обжаловать