# Добровольная отставка модератора A K

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Я решил добровольно уйти с поста модератора сообщества. (С сайта я не ухожу, наоборот я думаю, что наконец-то появится время читать и отвечать на вопросы по шарпу)

Принятое решение является давним, тщательно продуманным. Ещё принимая новые обязанности я знал, что это -- лишь на конкретный определённый срок, год-два. Ротация и сменяемость для меня не пустой звук и я считаю важным, чтобы срок действия ромба был ограничен, а не "бриллианты навсегда".

Мы обсуждали ситуацию с Андреем Suvitruf несколько месяцев назад в модчате и договорились, что для сайта будет лучше, если подадим в отставку одновременно, чтобы не проводить выборы слишком часто. (Я изначально планировал подавать позже, ну где-то через полгода)

Чтобы избежать возможных спекуляций и слухов я сразу хочу пояснить следующее. У меня нет каких-то конфликтов с кем-то из текущего модсостава, с Николаем или другими сотрудниками. Уход добровольный, тщательно продуманный, поэтому отговаривать меня бессмысленно и ненужно.

Формально я никакого заявления ещё не подал, помогу новоизбранным кандидатам освоиться в новой роли, думаю, что месяца более чем достаточно, так что где-то через месяц ромб и снимут.

Спасибо коллегам по модерированию, их советам и помощи. Спасибо постоянным участникам кто делает важную работу в очередях проверки. Отдельное спасибо тем, кто принимает участие в обсуждении тем на мета-сайте. Спасибо тем, кто задаёт интересные вопросы и пишет содержательные ответы. Не прощаюсь — просто подвожу черту под определённым периодом в жизни.

Comment: О, как понеслось. Такими темпами недалеко и до аналогичных постов от товарищей Пу и Лу...

Comment: Так, 3-ий в течении года, это модераторский-исход?

Comment: @0xdb мы это с AK давно обсуждали уже. Просто ждали проведения выборов, чтоб уйти только после появления замены)

Comment: @A k, @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik очень жаль, что вы приняли такое решение ((( Мне лично, очень нравилось, как вы работаете, как решаете и помогаете решать вопросы. Очень жаль

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо! Может на след. выборах опять выдвинусь)

Comment: Спасибо за службу :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь сообществу!

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik кстати, а есть подать заявку на текущие? :) но там, наверное, кнопка загреена.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ могу подать)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik было бы интересно посмотреть, ну и багрепортов добавить на MSE

Comment: @αλεχολυτ смог :D

Comment: @0xdb " 3-ий в течении года". В течение.

Comment: ‎‏‎‏‎‏M‎‏я‏y.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: При увольнении обязательно писать пост в соц сети?)

Comment: @Ilnar отставка модератора, и вообще изменение модераторского состава - значимое событие для сообщества. Если вам это безразлично - это ваше дело.

Answer (score 17):

Очень жаль. Вы и @Suvitruf, насколько я заметил, были самыми активными модераторами.

<sub>Ну еще Qwertiy (но он "не считает правильным уходить из модераторов").</sub>

**Большое cпасибо за огромный вклад в наше сообщество и надеюсь Вы не уйдете, а будете участвовать в статусе обычных участников вместе с Suvitruf'ом!**

Comment: что так громко то...

Comment: @eri вы просто слишком близко к мегафону ;)

Answer (score 15):

Большое спасибо за ваш вклад в развитие сообщества и русскоязычной базы знаний!

Часто наблюдал вашими диалогами с другими ребятами в чате модераторов. На мой взгляд, вы добавили интересную уникальную перспективу к команде модераторов.

Было приятно с вами работать! Спасибо!

Comment: Николай, спасибо за тёплые слова. Мне самому этот опыт модерирования на so дал много интересного и полезного опыта. Отдельно хочу сказать про атмосферу в модчатике. Могу сказать, что после некоторого момента "притирки" во многом именно ты и Андрей создали такую рабочую атмосферу.

Answer (score 11):

Понимаю и поддерживаю ваше решение.

Я в свое время тоже прошел через это и также [подавал заявление](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1777/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/1785#1785) - это было 5 лет назад.

Наверное надо ротацию модераторов сделать более частой что ли... Раз в полгода, например.