# Причины, по которым необходимо переименовать "Нормы поведения" в "Соглашение о поведении" или в "Правила поведения"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, нормы-поведения

## Нормы поведения

### 1. О понятии

Само понятие "нормы" подразумевает "обычность", "естественность", "само собой разумеющееся" для *определённого круга лиц (существ)*, ибо что "норма" для волка, не есть хорошо для овцы. Т.е. это относительное понятие.

### 2. С помощью "норм" приписываем сообществу качества, которых нет, дабы их считать "нормальными" (т.е. обычными)

Читаем на странице /conduct

> Нормы поведения помогают создавать сообщество, в основе которого лежит
>   доброта, сотрудничество и взаимное уважение.

Т.е. подразумевается, что такого сообщества пока нет, ибо "доброта, сотрудничество и взаимное уважение" для некоторых членов общества сейчас не являются "нормой" и эти "правила" имеют целью: это, если не исправить, то хотя бы не усугублять. Так как весьма затруднительно навязать людям чувство "взаимного уважения", но вот определённым образом влиять на них возможно, дабы они не посылали друг друга "за звёздочкой".

### 3. Оказывается "нормы" можно изменять

> Мы обязуемся обеспечивать соблюдение норм поведения и постоянно
>   улучшать их.

Мы это кто? Руководство, пользователи, кто-то ещё? Кто бы там ни был, выражение "постоянно улучшать их" подразумевает изменение, доработку. Т.е. эти некие "нормы" (в сущности положения) подвергаются изменению, из чего можно сделать вывод, что если нечто считалось "нормальным" сегодня, уже завтра может рассматриваться как "отклонение", а это не так: обычность, "нормальность" общества не зависит от волеизъявления "улучшающих нормы поведения" в той степени, чтобы считать "новые правки" новой привычной действительностью общественного поведения. Можно лишь предложить, объяснить, заставить (в определённой степени) или внедрить, минуя сознания, используя ползучие приёмы основанные на постепенных изменениях. Нечто подобное мы наблюдаем в нашей жизни, когда осознанно не можем сказать, когда именно у подростка изменился голос или появились предательские морщины вместе с болью в пояснице, спустя года.

### 4. Добровольная всеобъемлемость "норм".

> Действие норм распространяется на всех участников сообщества «Stack
>   Overflow на русском», а также участников других сообществ Stack
>   Exchange, нашу команду, модераторов сообществ и любого, кто оставляет
>   сообщения на каком-либо сайте вопросов и ответов или в чатах сети.

Здесь чёрным по белому сказано, что если вы согласились быть пользователем площадок сети StackExchange, посредством оставления сообщений в них, то вы соглашаетесь с положениями, указанными в этих самых "нормах", что есть нечто иное как **соглашение**. В данном случае это **соглашение о поведении**.

### Заключительная часть

В свете выше рассмотренных причин и доводов, касающихся природы "норм", их происхождения и согласительной составляющей оных, а также искусственной изменяемости и "принудительном" воплощении в жизнь, считаю, что данное наименование вводит пользователей в заблуждение относительно сути данного явления и поэтому предлагаю заменить его на то, чем в сущности оно и является, а именно соглашением и правилом, проистекающем из него, если точнее **"Соглашением о поведении" СоП** или **"Правилом поведения"**.

Answer (score 7):

Словоблудие какое-то, если честно.

**Норма** — правило или предписание, действующее в определённой сфере и требующее своего выполнения. Не вижу каких-то проблем, почему наши нормы не являлись бы нормами.

> Т.е. подразумевается, что такого сообщества пока нет

С чего это? Если бы там было будущее время, то я бы понял. А там:

> Нормы поведения помогают создавать сообщество

**Помогают создавать**. Сообщество не статично, в нём постоянно происходят какие-то процессы. Нормы меняются.

> Оказывается "нормы" можно изменять

Да. Когда-то считалось нормальным держать чёрных рабов, сейчас нет. Когда-то считалось нормальным, что "место женщины на кухне", теперь, к счастью, люди борются с этим.

Если вас смущает именно слово "норма", то я бы ещё понял предложение заменить его на "кодекс". Но соглашение - это же совсем из другой песни.

Comment: "Норма — правило или предписание, действующее в определённой сфере и требующее своего выполнения." на основании чего? На работе, скажем, на основании трудового соглашения, а здесь, на основании того, что некто добровольно согласился быть участником сети StackExchange.

Comment: Ну, речь не о том, что "нормы" неизменяемы, а о том, что одних правок в сообщениях недостаточно, чтобы нечто считалось "нормальным" (обычным).

Comment: Вот скорее "кодекс" это "из другой песни", лучше уж тогда просто "Правила поведения".

Answer (score 4):

Не соглашусь с вами. И вообще, вы нечестно играете: весь ваш текст одна сплошная подмена понятий и передергивание. По пунктам:

1. Все нормально (каламбур однако) :)
2. Про "существование сообщества" это очень толстое передергивание и подмена. Типа если сообщество не выполняет свои правила то его нет, серьёзно?
3. Тут вода и словоблудие. Да, представьте правила, нормы, законы и что там еще нужно периодически менять.
4. Опять жирная подмена размером с авианосец. "Соглашения" не от того что кто-то с ними согласился, а от того что была выполнена процедура свободного согласования. Когда каждый участник мог внести или отвергнуть изменения в общий текст соглашений. Свободного, значит что никто участнику не мешал и не принуждал.

Могу предположить, что ваш текст это реакция на последние важные события: [Уход модераторов сети Stack Exchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9549/180450) и [Добровольная отставка модератора PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9559/180450). Если вы хотите добиться чего-то важного и полезного, уверяю вас подмена понятий не поможет. Например, по вашему получается, что правила которые навязываются сверху нужно назвать "соглашениями", но, извините, это совсем грубый обман. Это законы, правила или скрижали, но никак не соглашения, уж лучше "нормы". Не нужно играть в слова это бесполезно и вредно, потому что обман.

Comment: 2. Такого, каким его хотят видеть, да, его нет.

Comment: 3. Правила, законы — да. Нормы меняются не пером, а спустя время. Время на принятие нового поведения.

Comment: "Например, по вашему получается, что правила которые навязываются сверху нужно назвать "соглашениями", но, извините, это совсем грубый обман." если перечитаете сообщение, то вряд ли найдёте там призыв переименовать "правила" в "соглашения". Речь только лишь про одно понятие, а именно "норма".

Answer (score 4):

**Согласен** что «Code of conduct» можно перевести и как «Правила поведения». Буквальный перевод «кодекс» режет слух поэтому приходится искать перевод подходящий по смыслу.

**Не согласен** что «Code of conduct» нельзя перевести как «Нормы поведения». Слово «[норма](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)» широко используется в значении «установленный порядок». Вот несколько примеров использования:

- [Кодекс этики членов ОПРФ](https://www.oprf.ru/about/1391/493/). Раздел 2. *Нормы поведения* членов общественной палаты.
- [Кодекс профессиональной этики адвоката](https://fparf.ru/documents/fpa-rf/documents-of-the-congress/the-code-of-professional-ethics-of-lawyer/). Раздел 1. Раздел первый. Принципы и нормы профессионального поведения адвокатов.
- [Руководство по социальной ответственности](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-r-iso-26000-2012). 4.7 Соблюдение международных норм поведения

**Не согласен** что «Соглашение о правилах» удачный перевод «Code of Conduct»

В данном случае это именно установленный компанией Stack Overflow порядок. Компания иногда прислушивается к мнению сообщества, но в целом оставляет за собой право внесения изменений в правила в одностороннем порядке.

«Соглашение» звучит как некий договор (например, лицензионное соглашение) который имеет определенную юридическую силу и который меняется только по согласованию обеих сторон. По-английски соглашение это скорее «agreement» или «contract».

**Не согласен** что изменение названия «Норм поведения» необходимо для сообщества.

Как бы Вы их не назвали, содержание и сущность норм поведения не изменится. Компания в принятии решения в любом случае будет опираться на английский текст, т.к. русский перевод по сути подготовлен русскоязычным сообществом.

**Кроме всего этого,** у Stack Overflow кроме норм поведения есть [пользовательское соглашение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) (Terms of service), которое написано юридическим языком и не переведено на русский.

**По пунктам:**

1. Этимология слова слабо связана с его современным употреблением. Немцы умеют говорить, некоторые даже по-русски. Врачи не всегда обманывают и редко лечат шептанием. Не стоит строить далеко идущие выводы из общего корня в словах «норма» и «нормальный».
2. Тоже что по первому пункту. Нормы в данном случае установленные правила, а не обвинение в ненормальности.
3. Тоже что по первому и второму пунктам.
4. Про согласие в нормах речи не идет. Нормы устанавливает компания Stack Overflow. Если Вас будут наказывать, то про согласие/несогласие не спросят.

**В итоге.** Пользы от переименования никакой. Ошибкой перевода «нормы» назвать сложно. Пользовательское соглашение уже есть и оно отличается от норм поведения.

Comment: Первого предложения мне хватило. За это +1. Что касается правоведов, ну, так у них там совсем другой язык: латинский по правилам русского, в большинстве своём.